# how to save the data of a query in a spool file in oracle

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, spool

I have created a script which is containing one query and , that query output should print in a `spool` file.

`spool D:\sqlpractice\abcd`

it creates the abcd file but that output data is not printing on that file. that output of query is printing on the `sqlplus` command prompt.

how to save that data in `spooled` file?

Comment: You must end the script with `spool off`

Comment: okay, I got it now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `spool off`, at that moment the output gets saved to the spoolfile. 
For example:

```
spool D:\sqlpractice\abcd
SELECT * FROM Dual; 
spool off;
```